# pix2pix - get intermediate layers output as PNG using Python

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I need some help with getting PNG images of [pix2pix](https://github.com/phillipi/pix2pix) intermediate layers (generators), using `pix2pix.py` file and Tensorflow, while run test session. thanks for helping.

Comment: So if youre able to generate a png from intermediate tensors you are good to go, right?

Comment: @Anuj yes. the default png comes from the last tensor. how can I generate a pngs from intermediate tensors?

Comment: I think, youll need to find a way to merge the outputs of different filter tensors into one and then generate a png from that tensor. Dont think there will be a package for that, youll need to write it yourself!

Comment: @Anuj thanks. I hope someone will help to figure it out.